# How to open a file from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem:

I have an AngularJS application. There I have a table, and a few input fields. One of the input fields is a text area.

I need have the code to take the data from the table, and place it into the input fields.

Now, the textarea field is there to take a large text, obviously.
And that large text, I don't need on my database.
I want to take the name of the file, from the table, and search in my folder, if that file exists, and if it does, I need it's content to be shown on the textarea.

Here is the code so far:

HTML page

```html
<label>Script ID:</label> 
    <input 
        name="scriptId" 
        type="text"
        ng-model="selectedScript.scriptId" 
        value="{{selectedScript.scriptId}}" 
        /> 
    <br /> 

    <label>File Name:</label> 
    <input 
        type="text" 
        ng-model="selectedScript.fileName"
        value="{{selectedScript.fileName}}" />
    <br />

<div id="container">
        <textarea ng-model="selectedScript.src"
            value="{{selectedScript.src}}" id="fileInfo"></textarea>
</div>

<table class="scripts">
    <tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
        <th>Script ID</th>
        <th>File Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr 
        ng-repeat="s in scripts | filter:searchField | orderBy:'scriptId'"
        ng-click="selectScript(s)" 
        ng-class="getSelectedClass(s)" >        

        <td>{{s.scriptId }}</td>
        <td>{{s.fileName }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the controller

```
//some function to show what attributes the script has
$scope.scripts.push({
    'scriptId' : selectedScript.scriptId,
    'fileName' : selectedScript.fileName,
    'src' : selectedScript.src,
    'userId' : 1 //hardcoded, for now
});

$scope.selectedScript = {};
$scope.selectedRow = null;

$scope.selectScript = function(script) { 
    $scope.selectedScript = script;
    //At this point i have the file name, i just need to open the 
    //file, and read it, and push the data to my textarea
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the file system like that, from JS.

There is simply no way to ***programatically*** access your computer's files, through JS.

Comment: k...i ll look for another way

Comment: Fortunately... !!